# Word: How to (user-friendly) revert Footnote References style to default?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, footnote

During re-formatting a large document major part of footsteps notes had their style changed (mostly to `Normal`). The original (inline) style `Footsteps reference` is still there, but is not assigned to most of references.

---

I'm able to create a macro for it.
**Simple macro for applying Style "Footnote Reference" to every Footnote Reference in an active document:**

```vb
Sub main()
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
        item.Reference.Style = wdStyleFootnoteReference
    Next item
End Sub
```

[`wdStyleFootnoteReference`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211923(v=office.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#wdbuiltinstyle) = -39

---

But for my collaborators macros are no-way.

Is there some **user-friendly way** how to select all these references and set appropriate style for them?

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the Footnote Reference style on all footnotes, use the Advanced Find/Replace function (located on the Home tab.)

The Find what: is set with a `^f`

And the Replace with: is set with a Style of `Footnote Reference`.

This does what the macro you shared does, but without a macro.

[image]

Comment: Thanks your answer is cool and useful, but it is not equivalent of my macro, because macro is selecting `footnote references` in text. Your solution select references just before `footnote` itself. (What I don't know how to do with VBA)..

Comment: [What your solution does](https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2021/01/08/0qaF.png) and [what my macro does](https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2021/01/08/DgX7.png)

Comment: Are you asking how to do that in VBA? I thought you were looking for a solution that didn’t use VBA because your collaborators didn’t want a macro. Also the solution I provided resets the style on all references if ReplaceAll is used.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. My "VBA remark" was only a "statement". The VBA in the original Question is working and does what I wanted. (for "numbers" in the text only). Your solution is working for "numbers under the bottom line" only. So I'd like to know, how to change style for "numbers" inside the text without using VBA.

Comment: @Lluser when I tested the Find/Replace that I shared, it corrected both references. The reference in the body, and the reference in the footnote listing itself. To do my test I changed the style on the reference in both places to Normal. Running the Find/Replace reset both to Footnote Reference. It’s perplexing why your results differ.